# Process32FirstW always returns false

Tags: c#, winapi, marshalling

Process32FirstW is suppose to return true when it finds process and return the first process in a PROCESSENTRY32W structure but it doesnt, so i cant enumerate it in Process32Next sadly. What is the reason it doesnt return true as a bool function? [([([( I have changed the struct deceleration )])])])]

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PROCESSENTRY32W
        {
            public uint dwSize;
            public uint cntUsage;
            public uint th32ProcessID;
            public IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID;
            public uint th32ModuleID;
            public uint cntThreads;
            public uint th32ParentProcessID;
            public int pcPriClassBase;
            public uint dwFlags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
            public string szExeFile;
        }; 
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32SnapshotRtlMoveMemory(UInt32 dwFlagsdes, UInt32 th32ProcessID);

        [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "Process32FirstW", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool Process32FirstW(IntPtr hSnapshot, IntPtr lppe);

        [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "Process32Next")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool Process32Next(IntPtr hSnapshot, IntPtr lppe);

        [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "CloseHandle")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        public static Dictionary<int, Process> get_process_list()
        {
            //Dictionary<string, Process> returnable_processes_ = new Dictionary<string, Process>();
            Dictionary<int, Process> returnable_processes_ = new Dictionary<int, Process>();
            IntPtr HANLDE_Processes = CreateToolhelp32SnapshotRtlMoveMemory(2,0);

            PROCESSENTRY32W p32Iw = new PROCESSENTRY32W();
            p32Iw.dwSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESSENTRY32W));
            IntPtr p32IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(p32Iw));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(p32Iw, p32IntPtr, false);
            bool blFirstProcess = Process32FirstW(HANLDE_Processes, p32IntPtr); // returns false no matter what?
            int x = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            if(blFirstProcess)
            { 

                do
                {
                    Marshal.PtrToStructure(p32IntPtr, p32Iw);
                    int PID = (int) p32Iw.th32ProcessID;
                    returnable_processes_.Add(PID, new Process());

                } 
                while(Process32Next(HANLDE_Processes, p32IntPtr));
            }





            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p32IntPtr);
            return returnable_processes_;
        }
```

Comment: Firstly, add `SetLastError=true` to your DLLImport declarations. Secondly, call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` after the call to Process32FirstW() returns false, and check the error code you get back - hopefully that will give you some more information.

Comment: Aside from all this, consider carefully first if what you're doing really can't be done with a call to `Process.GetProcesses()`, possibly with some unmanaged calls per process if you really need to do things the managed APIs can't. Second, assuming they can't, consider writing a C++/CLR wrapper instead of doing it exclusively in C#; this allows for much smoother interop compared to constant `Marshal` calls.

Comment: Why did you call it `CreateToolhelp32SnapshotRtlMoveMemory`? That looks like it can only confuse the readers of the code (i.e. you!) Also the code you provided does not compile. So it isn't the code you are running. Asking us to help with code requires you to provide the actual code. Don't provide fake code. Make a [mcve] and provide that. After you have proved to yourself that the [mcve] is correct.

Comment: Going to be so much easier if you get rid of the gnarly heap allocation code and pass by ref a local variable of type `PROCESSENTRY32W`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the code compiles fine, that is on you, just when i debug it  i find that Process32FirstW returns false

Comment: Thanks @MatthewWatson I will try that

Comment: @MatthewWatson Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() returns 24 as an int?
is there a place where i can find the error codes?

Comment: No. The code does not compile. For instance this does not compile `public static extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32SnapshotRtlMoveMemory(UInt32dwFlagsdes, UInt32 th32ProcessID);`. I have quite some experience dealing with this type of question. I know how to do this. Please heed my advice.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521778/error-bad-length-when-calling-process32first-in-windows-7

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have compiled this multiple times in visual studio, and i just compiled it now to confirm it, it compiles fine as for the other question i have done what they have done as you can see in my code i have declared  p32Iw variable and its new so its null, and i have assigned its dwsize still doesnt work

 do you have using System.Runtime.InteropServices; in the begining? thats probably why it doesnt compile on your side

Comment: I'm quite sure your code compiles. It's just that your code isn't the code that we are looking at. I'm sure you will agree that the line of code I showed in my comment above does not compile.

Comment: You should get rid of the pointless heap allocation (as I said) and use a `ref` parameter. And then when the system tells you that the length is wrong, the length is wrong. Probably your struct has the wrong declaration. We don't know because we can't see it. Because you didn't provide a [mcve]. You are new here I know. Now is your chance to learn how to get the most out of the site. I have no problems calling this API, but I can't help unless you provide the necessary details.

Comment: Just gave the struct

Comment: Your struct declaration is completely wrong. Only the first field is correct! I haven't got time now to correct it. Try some websearch and perhaps find some existing code that gets it right. I'm also reluctant to write an answer because I'd really need to tackle all the issues mentioned in the comments above too. Sorry.

Comment: Error code 24 is ERROR_BAD_LENGTH.  That's accurate, the structure declaration is off quite a bit.  Finding somebody else's code isn't going to be that easy, given that this doesn't do anything that Process.GetProcesses() doesn't already do better.  But you can [look here](https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/PROCESSENTRY32.html) for a correct declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much @HansPassant

Comment: Hmmmm even after using the correct declaration its still doesnt work, it still says ERROR_BAD_LENGTH

@HansPassant

Comment: That declaration is fine but you have to make sure the character sets match

Comment: what character set. you mean public string szExeFile; ? @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Why is it called RtlMoveMemory? Why don't you use a ref param? And yes the character set of the string doesn't match that required by the W version of the function. All this is well documented. I fear a big part of your problem is that you are trying to write the code by cut and paste without gaining a solid understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a charset problem. You use the ***W version of api. The actual type of `PROCESSENTRY32W.szExeFile` is `wchar_t`, which is 2 bytes, so the structure size you passed is 260 bytes shorter(you can simply try `p32Iw.dwSize + 260`, `Process32FirstW` will return ture, if we are regardless of the subsequent execution).
Fix the struct declaration and run the "C/C++ Programming" C# code.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct PROCESSENTRY32 
   { 
      public uint dwSize; 
      public uint cntUsage; 
      public uint th32ProcessID; 
      public IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID; 
      public uint th32ModuleID; 
      public uint cntThreads; 
      public uint th32ParentProcessID; 
      public int pcPriClassBase; 
      public uint dwFlags; 
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=260)] public string szExeFile; 
    };
```

But according to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8), `Marshal.StructureToPtr` and `Marshal.PtrToStructure` are out of date and we should avoid using it. And this way of passing values through pointers is usually replaced by references in C#.

First, declare charset and reference parameters for `Process32First` and `Process32Next`

```
[DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "Process32First", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool Process32First(IntPtr hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32W lppe);

[DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "Process32Next", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool Process32Next(IntPtr hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32W lppe);
```

Then, Pass the ref type of `PROCESSENTRY32W`:

```
bool blFirstProcess = Process32First(HANLDE_Processes, ref p32Iw); // returns false no matter what?
if (blFirstProcess)
{
   do
   {
      //Marshal.PtrToStructure(p32IntPtr, p32Iw);
      int PID = (int)p32Iw.th32ProcessID;
      returnable_processes_.Add(PID, new Process());
      Console.WriteLine(p32Iw.szExeFile);
   }
   while (Process32Next(HANLDE_Processes, ref p32Iw));
 }
```

Summarize, a minimal, compilable example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
         public struct PROCESSENTRY32W
        {
            public uint dwSize;
            public uint cntUsage;
            public uint th32ProcessID;
            public IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID;
            public uint th32ModuleID;
            public uint cntThreads;
            public uint th32ParentProcessID;
            public int pcPriClassBase;
            public uint dwFlags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)] public string szExeFile;
        };
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32SnapshotRtlMoveMemory(UInt32 dwFlagsdes, UInt32 th32ProcessID);

        [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "Process32First", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool Process32First(IntPtr hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32W lppe);

        [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "Process32Next", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool Process32Next(IntPtr hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32W lppe);

        [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "CloseHandle")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
        public static Dictionary<int, Process> get_process_list()
        {
            //Dictionary<string, Process> returnable_processes_ = new Dictionary<string, Process>();
            Dictionary<int, Process> returnable_processes_ = new Dictionary<int, Process>();
            IntPtr HANLDE_Processes = CreateToolhelp32SnapshotRtlMoveMemory(2, 0);

            PROCESSENTRY32W p32Iw = new PROCESSENTRY32W();
            int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESSENTRY32W));
            p32Iw.dwSize = Convert.ToUInt32(size);
            //IntPtr p32IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(p32Iw));
            //Marshal.StructureToPtr(p32Iw, p32IntPtr, false);
            bool blFirstProcess = Process32First(HANLDE_Processes, ref p32Iw); // returns false no matter what?
            int x = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            if (blFirstProcess)
            {

                do
                {
                    int PID = (int)p32Iw.th32ProcessID;
                    returnable_processes_.Add(PID, new Process());
                    Console.WriteLine(p32Iw.szExeFile);

                }
                while (Process32Next(HANLDE_Processes, ref p32Iw));
            }
            return returnable_processes_;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            get_process_list();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```